# How do I specify the number of Inputs to store?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Programming newbie here.

The first line of the input contains an integer N, the number of cases. 
N lines follow each line containing an array, P, with details on the case.

How do I do the IO thing so it keeps prompting the user to input/store N number of cases?

For pseudocode (because I can't get it to work) I'm thinking it should be something along the lines of:

```
for however many times N:
take P as raw_input and put it somewhere like another array?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want:

```
inputs = []
nums = 5    #number of times to take input
for _ in range(nums):
    inputs.append(raw_input('Please enter text: '))
```

OR

```
inputs = []
nums = 5    #number of times to take input
for i in range(nums):
    inputs.append(raw_input('Please enter input {}: '.format(i+1)))


#Run your script
Please enter input 1: 
Please enter input 2: 
Please enter input 3: 
Please enter input 4: 
Please enter input 5:
```